# Removing part of a string in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've been looking at the re documentation, searching the web, and trying so many things for a couple of hours now and still cannot find out a way to remove a certain part of a string.

So, the string will look like this,

> Linda Lost (Secret Icecone Incorporated) lost their Kronos in Osmon (The Forge). Final Blow by Liberty Prime (Exit-Strategy) flying in a Arbitrator. Total Value: 1,865,802,910.96 ISK

Basically all the names and stuff in the string will change when the string is pulled from the meta data of the website. The only thing that is for sure is things like 'Final Blow by ', 'Total Value: ' and ' ISK' will be the same.

So, what I have been trying to figure out what to do is to remove the whole 'Total Value: 1,865,802,910.96 ISK' part and return that came before it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `someString[:someString.find('Total Value:')]`

Comment: Awsome! Thanks for the help. It worked great.

Comment: `s.split('Total Value:')[0]`

Comment: `re.search(r'.*(?=Total Value:)', s).group()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex as follows,

```
pat = re.compile(r'(.*?)Total Value: [\d,.]* ISK')
m = pat.match(s)
m.group(1)
'Linda Lost (Secret Icecone Incorporated) lost their Kronos in Osmon (The Forge). Final Blow by Liberty Prime (Exit-Strategy) flying in a Arbitrator. '
```

Or you could do the following hack

```
s.rsplit('.',2)[0]
'Linda Lost (Secret Icecone Incorporated) lost their Kronos in Osmon (The Forge). Final Blow by Liberty Prime (Exit-Strategy) flying in a Arbitrator'
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

```
t = "Linda Lost (Secret Icecone Incorporated) lost their Kronos in Osmon (The Forge). Final Blow by Liberty Prime (Exit-Strategy) flying in a Arbitrator. Total Value: 1,865,802,910.96 ISK"
```

where = t.rfind(" Total")

print(t[:where])

Comment: Using `Total.+` is dangerous, since `Total` might appear as part of one of the names. A more specific pattern, or non-greedy repetition might make it work safely.

Comment: Don't you see '$' in the pattern? It means that described pattern must be mached at the end.

Comment: It's the start of the pattern that's the problem. What if, instead of `Linda Lost`, the name as the start of the string was `Foo Total`. The pattern you've given would throw everything away but `Foo`. Note, I may have you at an advantage here, since I know what the string being described means (it's part of a killmail from the MMO Eve Online). I would not be at all surprised to see players or corporations (Eve's guilds) deliberately using names that will break careless killmail parsing code (like `Total Value` or `Final Blow by`).

Comment: Friend, you were right. My code was not flexible. Therefore I changed the code and it is now more simple.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
t = "Linda Lost (Secret Icecone Incorporated) lost their Kronos in Osmon (The Forge). Final Blow by Liberty Prime (Exit-Strategy) flying in a Arbitrator. Total Value: 1,865,802,910.96 ISK"

t.split('Total Value:')[0]
```